# Increase CDH4 diskspace

Tags: centos, vmware-player, hadoop

Initially i was using bundled CDH3 VM (Cloudera Version of Hadoop) later, i removed CDH3 and now I am using CDH4 on CentOS as a VM (through VMWare player) with host machine as Win7 64bit. I am in the need of increasing the diskspace (Since CDH3 VMDK comes with 4.7GB space). There is an option of expanding the diskspace in the vmware player settings. But i dont want to crash my VM before doing something bad. Is there any suggestion or resource that you can point me to increase root diskspace in CentOS, or else configuring a new diskspace for hadoop dfs in VMware Player.